Discontinuity in perfect substitutes demand function
For perfect substitutes preferences $U(x_{1}, x_{2}) = ax_{1} + bx_{2}$ and income $m$, the demand curve for $x_{1}$ is:
\begin{equation}
x_{1} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} > \frac{a}{b} \\
{[0, \frac{m}{p_{1}}}] & \text{if } \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{a}{b} \\
\frac{m}{p_{1}} & \text{if } \frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} < \frac{a}{b}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
For the equality case ($\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}} = \frac{a}{b}$), shouldn't we choose one endpoint of $[0, \frac{m}{p_{1}}]$ so that the function $x_{1}(p_{1})$ is well-defined and passes the vertical line test? Is it arbitrary which endpoint we use?

The rigorous definition of demand says that it is a correspondence (i.e., set-valued mapping), and need not be a function. In your example, the demand for perfect substitutes is a correspondence. If you want to restrict it to be a function, then yes, you have to pick some value for the equality case (but you need to always pick the same value for the same function, e.g., one demand function is piecewise linear with $x_1(p,m) = 0$ if $p_1/p_2 \geq a/b$; $x_1(p,m) = m/p_1$ if $p_1/p_2 < a/b$.
